# What is vendor.min.js?

Tags: javascript

This script was used in the project im working on. So I wanted to see the documentation of what it does. I learned that `.min` is for minified versions. But I still couldn't find out what `vendors.js` does. I was only able to find out the git repository with only code. Can anyone please tell me what this  script does or where i can find the document?

Comment: It is just a js file provided by the seller/author of the theme or plugins. It may include number of (non)required dependencies in a single file to be used in your project or part of the project.

Answer (score 0):

It is a third party library that is used for form validation.